Missing "Automatic Date & Time" option / NTP not supported
I have a couple of PCs both running 24.04.1 LTS. On one of them when I go to Settings -> System -> Date & Time there is no Automatic Date & Time option. It just shows Date & Time with the ability to manually set the date/time.
When I ran timedatectl on the problem PC I get:
               Local time: Fri 2024-10-04 11:26:30 BST
           Universal time: Fri 2024-10-04 10:26:30 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2024-10-04 10:26:30
                Time zone: Europe/London (BST, +0100)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no

And when I run timedatectl set-ntp on I get:
Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported

So I understand why the option is missing in settings (NTP not supported) but I don't understand why it's not supported or what I need to do to fix it.
Can anyone help further?

In your system you are using systemd-timesyncd.service that is a service to manage your system time.
First, check that this service is active and if not, activate it.
sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service

then:
timedatectl set-ntp true

If the problem is not solved, please post the log about this service
Make sure that the other time management services are no longer active such as ntpd or chrony.

Thanks for the info, as it turns out, the service was not even installed (and neither were any others). I have no idea why, but all I needed to do was install the service you specified with sudo apt-get install systemd-timesyncd and ntp was setup and the GUI is now showing the missing option.

Generally, there are three different potential time synchronization services that can be used in Ubuntu:

ntp.service: the old implementation of the NTP protocol.
chrony.service: the newer implementation of the NTP protocol.
systemd-timesyncd.service: a simpler implementation of the NTP protocol, mainly for client type computers like desktop computers.

To check which one (if any) is active on my system, I use this command sequence:
$ for s in ntp chrony systemd-timesyncd ; do echo -e '\n*** Checking '$s'...\n' ; systemctl status $s; done

Only one of the above should be active.
